# Android Programming crop background image

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to display an image as background in my app. Now I used this statement: `android:background="@drawable/background"` in `<LineraLayout>`. Here is the `.xml` Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="overbit.user.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I get this output:

[image]

But I want it like this:

[image: as]

Maybe someone of you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap), which allows to do it. First you need to create a drawable resource as follows (let it be a file in the project resources `res/drawable/mybg.xml` ):

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

And then specify it as a background resource in your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="overbit.user.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can I do it programatically? i.e. I want an image from server and show it as cropped... It it possible using picasso ?

Comment: This is not working when the drawable is a vector (SVG), It crashes on runtime. Do you know how to make it work with a vector?

Comment: @Shirane85 according to the documentation, [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Bitmap) is compatible with `png`, `jpeg` and `gif` formats only. You cannot make **it** work with a vector. The only drawable resource supporting `svg` files i'm aware of is [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) but it doesn't have similar setting. If you don't want to put a lot of effort into it, i think [drWisdom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910037/5690248) should be a best fit.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yeah, thats what i ended up doing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the image's size itself in photoshop or something to achieve the desired result (still this can be very difficult because of various screen sizes of android smartphones). A workaround can be to change your parent layout to Relativelayout and then use a an imageview to show your picture like this:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent" //make sure its match parent
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"// and this one also
>         android:src="@drawable/yourBackgroundImage"
>         android:scaleType="..."/>
>     <LinearLayout>put your childviews here</LinearLayout>
> ```

there are 4-5 options available for **android:scaleType**... experiment with them, till you get your desired result. Also note that you need to use **android:src** rather than **android:background** attribute of the imageview

Comment: @MyNewName I find it a convenient and easy way. The scaleType attrib in imageview does offer you useful flexibility. Adding an extra ImageView does not really  overburden your Layout (unless it is already quite cluttered).

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by using [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html).

From the docs:

> BitmapRegionDecoder can be used to decode a rectangle region from an
>   image. BitmapRegionDecoder is particularly useful when an original
>   image is large and you only need parts of the image.

It allows you to decode a Rect area of a particular Bitmap fairly easily, the only thing you need to do is calculate your Rect region to decode relative to the Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

In android the position of an ImageView is determined by the top left side of the image. I am assuming that the x direction is 1/3rd of the width from the start point. Now we can set the pivot. Basically the location of the pivot point, is a location around which the view will rotate and scale.

```
int displacementX = ImageView.getWidth() / 3;
int displacementY = 10;
imgview.setPivotX((float)displacementX);
imgview.setPivotY((float)displacementY);
```

Now that we have set the pivot we can use a scale type to fit the image.

```
imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```